# this keyword is window object within a constructor function

Tags: javascript, this

Ok, so I thought I understood this (no pun intended), but apparently not.

```
var Constructor = function () {
    var internalFunction = function () {
        return this === window;
    };
    this.myMethod = function () {
        alert(internalFunction());
    };
};
var myObj = new Constructor();
myObj.myMethod();
```

This alerts `true`. Why can't the internal function see `this` as the object? Instead I have to use `alert(internalFunction.call(this));` in `myMethod`.

**Edit:** I was looking for an explanation as to why `this` is assigned in that way, not workarounds such as `var self = this;`, etc. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: None of the answers to this questions use `that`. I feel betrayed.

Comment: @missingno: I dislike `that`. It's non-descriptive. That said, my own choice in my answer is no better :)

Comment: +1 for unintentional pun

Comment: Coming back years later... I tend to use the lowercase version of the constructor. `function Note() { var note = this;` I think it makes for a pretty easy-to-read convention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is not bound until the function is called and is dependent on how the function is called. You could think of it as an extra parameter implicitly passed to the function.

In this case, the problem is that you're calling `internalFunction` using `internalFunction()`. The `this` value is set either by calling a function as a method (as in `foo.bar()` or `foo["bar"]()`) or by setting `this` explictly via `call()` or `apply()`. Your call is doing neither so `this` reverts to the global object.

The simplest way to achieve what you want in this case while keeping `internalFunction` private is to store a reference to `this` inside the constructor function:

```
var Constructor = function() {
    var thisObj = this;

    var internalFunction = function () {
        return thisObj === window;
    };

    thisObj.myMethod = function () {
        alert(internalFunction());
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense... `this` is assigned at call-time, so by calling `internalFunction()` I'm implicitly calling `window.internalFunction()`. Well explained.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: I'm not getting into a discussion on that and it was a needless tweak to the original code on my part, so I've reverted it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Because of functional scoping rules, `this` is reassigned inside each function... I would store a copy of your object as `self` and use it accordingly...

```
var Constructor = function () {

    var self = this;

    var internalFunction = function () {
        return self === window;
    };
    this.myMethod = function () {
        alert(internalFunction());
    };
};
var myObj = new Constructor();
myObj.myMethod();
```

Should give you the output you expect.

***SIDENOTE***

This is a fairly precarious practice that javascript has created, mainly because if you forget the `new` keyword when using `Constructor`, you **will** get `this` referring to the `window` (god) object so you'll be attaching `myMethod` to the window without warning.

Answer (score 2):

There are five ways to call a function in JavaScript. The value of `this` depends on which you choose:

1. **Global function call** (e.g. `myFunction()`). No explicit value for `this` is given. The value of `this` will be the default object (`window` in a browser).
2. **Method call** (e.g. `obj.myFunction()`). The value of `this` is the object on which the method was invoked (`obj` in this case).
3. **Using the `call` method** (e.g. `myFunction.call(obj)`). The value of `this` is provided explicitly (in this case `obj`).
4. **Using the `apply` method** (e.g. `myFunction.apply(obj)`). The value of `this` is provided explicitly (in this case `obj`).
5. **Constructor function** (e.g. `new MyFunction()`). The value of `this` is a newly-created object provided by the runtime.

Each of the five is explained in more detail here:

- http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its a scope issue  try something like:

```
var Constructor = function () {
    var $this = this;
    var internalFunction = function () {
        return $this === window;
    };
    this.myMethod = function () {
        alert(internalFunction());
    };
};
var myObj = new Constructor();
myObj.myMethod();
```