# Why does `this` refer to the global object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette application with a module defined below.  When I run this application, the console log statement prints out `@` as the window object.  When the `list` method is run, I thought that `this` (`@`) would refer to the `List.Controller` object.  What am I missing?

```
###
The Header list controller.
###
define [
    'cs!app',
    'cs!./view',
    'cs!modules/header/entities'
], (
  App,
  View
) ->
  App.module 'Header.List', (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
    List.Controller =
      list: ->
        console.log(@)
        headers = App.request 'header:entities'
        view = new View.Headers {collection: headers}
        App.headerRegion.show view

      setActiveHeader: (headerUrl) ->
        headers = App.request 'header:entities'
        header = headers.find (header) -> (header.get 'url') == headerUrl
        header.select()
        headers.trigger 'reset'

    App.commands.setHandler 'header:setActive', (headerUrl) ->
      List.Controller.setActiveHeader headerUrl

  App.Header.List.Controller
```

**Update**

This is the module that calls the list method:

```
###
The Header module.
###

define [
    'cs!app',
    'cs!./list/controller'
], (
  App,
  listController
) ->
  App.module 'Header', (Module, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
    Module.startWithParent = false

  App.module 'Routers.Header', (ModuleRouter, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
    class ModuleRouter.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
      appRoutes: {}

      executeAction = (action, args) ->
        action(args)

      API =
        list: ->
          executeAction listController.list

      App.Header.on 'start', ->
        API.list()

      App.addInitializer ->
        new ModuleRouter.Router {listController: API}

  App.Header
```

Comment: Where is the call for the function list?

Comment: I added the call in my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is calling method `list` of object `listController` with context of `window` (global).

This happened because you called method this way: `executeAction listController.list` and from `executeAction` this is just calling method normal way: `action(args)`

You can bind method to the class (with `_.bind`) or use `call` or `apply` method of js `Function` (bind way is easier):

Bind (`_.bind(action, context)`:

```
executeAction _.bind(listController.list, listController)
```

Calling (or applying) with another context (`method.call(context, arg1, ..)` or `method.apply(context, argsArray)`)

```
  executeAction = (context,action, args) ->
    action.call(context, args)

  API =
    list: ->
      executeAction listController, listController.list
```

Comment: I used your last example and it works like a charm -- and I think I understand what is going on now.  The only thing I am looking at is ekerens option.

Comment: I went with this option.  I also am looking at the requirement for the extra level of indirection I am using with the executeAction piece.  Thanks for the help to all.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `_.bindAll(this)` in initialize function, just add:

```
initialize:->
  _.bindAll(this, "list") // Like @mu mentioned in the comment, function name is required
```

**EDIT**:

Although @KiT-O is correct and the caller can bind the function to the Controller using `_.bind` function. This should not be the caller responsibility, The function needs to be binded to its correct context and the caller shouldn't care about/know it.

That is why I prefer the `_.bindAll` solution although it adds more boilerplate code to Backbone

Comment: I implemented this by adding   App.Header.List.addInitializer -> _.bindAll(App.Header.List.Controller, 'list', 'setActiveHeader') into my Header list controller.  This works, but seems cumbersome compared to KiT O's solution -- I'd have to maintain the list of functions.

Comment: This won't work with newer versions of Underscore: ["**methodNames** are required."](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll)

Comment: @Erik - I disagree :), see Edit where I explain why

Comment: @ekeren I'd agree with you if it wasn't for the way in which I was calling the method.  If you call the method in context via App.Header.List.Controller.list then everything works fine.  As I'm doing it, the caller is adding a layer of indirection via the executeAction part and therefore has accepted the responsibility of setting the context as well.

Comment: Also, my controller is just a dictionary, so there is no initialize function called.

Comment: Right,  I missed it, I thought you are using marionette controller... cool

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not bound until the function is called and is dependent on how the function is called. You could think of it as an extra parameter implicitly passed to the function.

In this case, I think you're calling your function using `controller()`. The `this` value is set either by calling a function as a method (as in `foo.bar()` or `foo["bar"]()`) or by setting this explicitly via `call()` or `apply()`. Your call is doing neither so this reverts to the global object.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982204).

Comment: I added my call in the update.  Since I am using listController.list, I thought that `this` would be bound to listController.

Comment: I was just notice that you are using `requirejs`. It seems that `requirejs` doesn't do any binding for 'this' keyword. For same code without requirejs, you will get your controller obj.

Comment: Reed more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650746/can-the-this-keyword-be-used-inside-a-requirejs-module

Comment: Interesting -- something I did not know.  I need to use requirejs though as it is how I assemble my asset pipeline.